# LAST_DDL_TIME Not Changing after create or replace package body again

Tags: oracle, ddl

On Nov 24 th, we created the `package body`. Again today we created (`create or replace`) the same package body object, but `last DDL date` has not changed. Is there any reason for this ?

Below is the query I'm using

```
SELECT object_name, object_type, created, last_ddl_time, status FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'xxxxxxxxx';
```

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328). Also asked here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192452/last-ddl-time-not-changing-after-compilation-of-package-body

Answer (score 1):

Your query could be wrong.

You need to add this to your WHERE clause:
 AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE BODY'

Your query would bring back the SPEC as well as the BODY and only the BODY was updated...theoretically since you're not saying exactly HOW you updated your package.

Comment: hi , it returns both spec and body .. both are not changed

Comment: then show us EXACTLY how you are updating your code - script, IDE, etc.